# Datetime unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'

Tags: python, loops, pandas, timedelta

I have working with a DataFrame structured as shown below. There are 200 unique columns and 45 unique dates.

```
             A100  A101       
DATE         
2016-09-25    NaN    4 
2016-10-23    6     NaN
```

I would like to determine the time between the first and last valid index. To do this I am using this for loop:

```
time_to_finish = dict()
for col in df:
    first_date = df[col].first_valid_index()
    last_date = df[col].last_valid_index()
    time = last_date - first_date
    time_to_finish[col] = time
```

The problem is I receive a Type error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'`

I don't understand why, because if I choose one column and find the date on its own I do not receive an error. For example this works fine:

```
first_date = df['A100'].first_valid_index()
last_date = df['A100'].last_valid_index()
last_date - first_date
```

and I receive a valid output like `Timedelta('20 days 00:00:00')`

Also, if I use first_date or last_date as the dictionary value instead of the variable time I get a full dictionary with no errors.

Why is this not working in the loop?

Comment: Try changing `first_date` to this: `first_date = col.first_valid_index()`

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error from your example. I get `{'A101': Timedelta('0 days 00:00:00'), 'A100': Timedelta('0 days 00:00:00')}`.

Comment: First and last valid index will give you the index value at first and last valid value. This error is telling you that you have nulls in your index at those spots

Comment: @piRSquared Thank you. I investigated my data and some columns have no values and the time_to_finish return None. I solved this issue simply with simple conditional statement `if first_date or last_date != None:`